# How can I run my app without zip files?

Tags: node-webkit

I'm coding a app for manage my projects SQL and I want put my files in a folder and execute without zip, just for easy edit. It's possible?

Comment: Well, presumably you'd not unzip all the JRE zips.  But, certainly, there is no need (in most environments) for your app to be in a zip file.  Hint: In the class path put the directory where you'd put the zip file.  But remember to have within the directory your full package structure (just like in a zip file).  Ie, if everything is in the com.myapp package then put a directory *containing* the com/myapp directories in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [nodebob](https://github.com/geo8bit/nodebob)
Make your html/js/css files in \nodebob\buildTools\nw folder .. And nw.exe to run it